# Swiper - How to move pointer to the next search item in the same line

Tags: swiper

I use swiper package to search and to navigate and I use `C-n` & `C-p` to search next and previous items. However, this doesn't go through the search items on the same line even though they are highlighted. I think it only cycles through the first items per given line.

Is there a way to move pointers to all search items even if they are on the same line?

I tries looking around for answers but was unsuccessful.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>C-'</kbd> (`swiper-avy`) to select any visible candidate. Even if there are many candidates on the same line.

Comment: Note that this default key binding will probably not work when running Emacs in [some terminal emulators](https://superuser.com/a/764449/725601). See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161725/230197.

Comment: Wow this is really excellent thank you abo-abo. But I would still be able to search for the 'next' search item in line like the default emacs search C-s if possible. Do you know if this possible?

Comment: `swiper-all` is more similar to `isearch` in this respect. `swiper` is line-based, with all advantages and disadvantages it brings.

Comment: Thanks abo-abo `swiper-all` seems very close to what I want. It seems to require a minimum of 3 characters to search. Is there a way to change the setting to have no such minimum requirement?

Comment: It's not reasonable. Without the limit, you'll just get the content of all your open buffers. Which is very slow.

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't isearch do exactly that?

Comment: isearch is designed to not show the amount of matches, therefore it can afford to be lazy. swiper-all isn't lazy: it will go through all possible matches. Even though only ~10 matches will be displayed, all of them are processed and counted.

Comment: Wow, thanks for `swiper-all`, it's *incredibly* power/useful ; On a related note, do you guys know how to get the "last search term" by pressing the same key that invoked swiper in the 1st place, like `isearch-forward` does when you press `C-s` twice?

Comment: `M-p` will show the previous search term from history.